# How to send several arguments to an solidity function using an array or a dictionary?

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, testrpc, meteor

Sorry in advance for my english I am French :)

I try to create a simple ethereum wallet. The idea is to allow the user to create a contract and to interact with it. I am using meteor, web3 and an testRPC node.

Basically for the interactions with the contract, for each contract I print on the browser the list of its functions . The user has just to click on the function he wants, then a pop up is printed to retrieve the arguments of the functions. Then I use web3 to send the request to a testRPC node and use a callback to print the result for the user.

The problem is that basically I don't obviously know in advance what is the function and the arg. So I index each of my html file with a special number and in combination with the dataBase, I retrieve the address of the contract, and all the informations about the function (using the ABI). Then I create three variables :

1. a variable `contract`
2. a variable `functionPrototype = abi of my function`
3. a dictionary `args = {nameArg1 : arg1, nameArg2 : arg2 etc...}`
   which    contains my arguments.

Then I have the contract, the name of the function and the args.

If the original Solidity function is :

- `function whatever(type nameArg1, type nameArg2) public{}`

I would like to use the following web3 function to send my request:

- `contract[functionPrototype.name](args, {from: account, gas: 350000},
  function(err, result){})`

But this request doesn't work . The following request, when I write all the args, works :

- `contract[functionPrototype.name](arg1, arg2, {from: account,
  gas: 350000}, function(err, result){})`

So the people can say : why you don't use the second request?

Because there are an infinite number of functions and I can't write all the arguments for each function. I need to automate all the process, so basically retrieve the arg and the name of the functions and using as input a dictionary or an array.

I have tried to use the function `apply`, **with an array** but it doesn't work either. I have all the time a `WebSocket is closed due to suspension.`

So do you know how I can send my arguments using a dictionary or an array to a solidity function?

Merci beaucoup!!!

And good luck for your jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was your code for the `apply` function? It should be

```
contract[funcName].apply(contract, paramsArray)
```

If your framework support ES2015 you can use [spread in function calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator#Spread_in_function_calls)

```
contract[funcName](...paramsArray)
```

Comment: Yes I have used  `contract[functionPrototype.name].apply(contract, dataSend,  {from: itemDB.account, gas: 350000}, function(err, result){}`  with dataSend equal to an array but each time I have `WebSocket connection to ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/893/uo39ftt_/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed due to suspension`.

Comment: You have to put all the parameters in the array, ie `{from: "0x", gas: 1..}`, and also the callback has to be in the array. You can do `dataSend.push({from: ...})`, and then `dataSend.push(function (err, result) { ...})` before the using apply. And then execute `contract[funcName].apply(contract, dataSend)`.

Comment: Thank you Ismael it works! During two days I was completely stuck. So thank you very much!